# How can I save a query from within a Django template so it is only preformed once?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to only save a query from within a template so it is only preformed once?

I have the following template:

```
{% for list in lists %}
<li>
  {{ list }} <span>{{ list.num_items }} item{{ list.num_items|pluralize }}</span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

And num_items is the following method in the list model:

```
    def num_items(self):
      return self.item_set.all().count()
```

This queries num_items twice. Is it possible to only do so once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [with](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-with). From the docs:

```
{% with business.employees.count as total %}
    {{ total }} employee{{ total|pluralize }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a method, use a property that caches the result.